# Closed form for $\int x^ne^{-x^m} \ dx\ ?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, gamma-function

While entertaining myself by [answering a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129959/to-find-out-the-consistent-estimator/2130239#2130239), the following problem arose.

For what natural numbers $n,m$ does the following undefined integral have a closed form

$$\int x^ne^{-x^m} \ dx\ ?$$

Closed form means that the antiderivative consists only of powers of $x^{...}$ and $x$ in $e^{-x^{...}}$.

I created the following matrix showing for different pairs of $n$ and $m$ the nature of the antiderivative.

$$\begin{matrix}
& m&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
n\\
1&&\checkmark&\checkmark&\Gamma&\text{erf}&\Gamma&\Gamma&\Gamma\\
2&&\checkmark&\text{erf}&\checkmark&\Gamma&\Gamma&\text{erf}&\Gamma&\\
3&&\checkmark&\checkmark&\Gamma&\checkmark&\Gamma&\Gamma&\Gamma&\\
4&&\checkmark&\text{erf}&\Gamma&\Gamma&\checkmark&\Gamma&\Gamma\\
5&&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\text{erf}&\Gamma&\checkmark&\Gamma\\
6&&\checkmark&\text{erf}&\Gamma&\Gamma&\Gamma&\Gamma&\checkmark\\
7&&\checkmark&\checkmark&\Gamma&\checkmark&\Gamma&\Gamma&\Gamma\\
\end{matrix}$$
$$$$
The $\checkmark$ sign stands for a closed form, "erf" signals that the antiderivative contains the  erf function , and $\Gamma$ signals that the antiderivative contains the [upper incomplete $\Gamma$ function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129959/to-find-out-the-consistent-estimator/2130239#2130239).

I have no clue. Does anybody?

Comment: Just as a starting point, how do you define closed form?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: If I may ask, did you consider negative values of $n,m$?

Comment: No, no, I did not dare to... Only naturals.

Comment: I imagine you started with the substitution $x^m=u$?

Comment: I've tried everything but nothing worked out in general.

Comment: Just for the fun, I added in the closed form.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: THX, but I cannot give one more $\checkmark$ or one more uppp.

Comment: Nah, I just do these things for the heck of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with a simple substitution $x=u^{1/m}$.  This gives us

$$I=\frac1m\int u^{(n+1)/m-1}e^{-u}\ du=\frac1m\gamma\left(\frac{n+1}m,x^m\right)+c$$

This trivially has closed forms for $\frac{n+1}m\in\mathbb N$ due to integration by parts.  Indeed, checking your table, it corresponds with every checkmark perfectly.

And just for the record, when $k\in\mathbb N$,

$$\int x^ke^{-x}\ dx=-e^{-x}\sum_{n=0}^k(k-n)!x^n+c$$

Comment: The erf comes from the relation $\gamma(1/2,x)=\sqrt{\pi}\text{erf}(x)$.